# Why do I get a blank page when using the 'Amazon ECS PHP Library'?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I'm having trouble using Amazon's [Product Advertising API (formerly ECS)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html) with the [Amazon ECS PHP Library](https://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library). I have the following code in my PHP file:

```
        require_once 'classes/amazonLookup.php';
        $client = new AmazonECS('API KEY', 'SECRET KEY', 'REGION', 'ASSOCIATE TAG');

        $response  = $client->category('Books')->search('PHP 5');
        echo $response;
```

But nothing happens when I view the PHP page. I got my access key and secret from AWS but have no idea what it means by associate tag. I can't find any mention of it on AWS. I've used a series of Xs as a placeholder.

Help? I need to get this working.

Comment: Have you tried leaving the associate tag empty? i.e. not specifying any value at all? Does `echo "Hello";` right before the `echo $response;` do anything at all or does the script not even get there? (and presumably that should be a `print_r` or `var_dump`, right?)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a blank page because you should use var_dump on the response to print the actual data instead of echo.

```
require_once 'classes/amazonLookup.php';
        $client = new AmazonECS('API KEY', 'SECRET KEY', 'REGION', 'ASSOCIATE TAG');

        $response  = $client->category('Books')->search('PHP 5');
        var_dump($response);
        //Or print_r($response);
```

This should work